# Domain administrator unable to connect via remote desktop after group policy deployment

Tags: windows, group-policy, domain, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop

The network I administer has two virtualized Windows Server DC and a handful of Windows clients. I wanted to enable remote desktop on all computers (some had it, some hadn't) via group policy and so I followed these guides - **minus the firewall part**, since it's for internal use only - :

- https://www.helpwire.app/blog/remote-desktop-group-policy/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PctGM1pcXkA

and applied the group policy to the entire domain. The result is that clients have indeed been updated and now show the remote desktop option as ON by default and greyed out. However for some reason the domain admin I had used up to that point to connect remotely was no longer able to do so to any computer, client or desktop. Normal users could still use remote desktop just fine.

I have since managed to fix the issue (domain admin can now access clients and servers via remote desktop) by following this solution:

- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/369614-domain-admins-cant-remote-into-any-machine

Now I'm left wondering what could have caused the problem to being with. Were the guides wrong or incomplete or must I have messed up along the way?

Comment: I think at a minimum there needs to be the report from gpresult /h on a system with the problem. And the output of whoami /groups for the impacted account. And the value of logon to terminal server right as seen in gpedit. Usually this occurs due to overwriting the value of the right or group membership.